# Tap Gesture Recognizer not received in custom UIView embedded in super view

Tags: ios, swift, events, uiview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I am trying to create a custom UIView/Scrollview named `MyScrollView` that contains a few labels (UILabel), and these labels receive tap gestures/events in order to respond to user's selections [image: See the below screen shot for the custom UIView].

In order to make the tap event work on the UILabels, I make sure they all have `userIteractionEnabled = true` and I created a delegate as below:

```
protocol MyScrollViewDelegate {
    func labelClicked(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
}
```

The custom UIView is being used in `ScrollViewController` that I created, this `ScrollViewController` implements the delegate method as well:

```
import UIKit
import Neon
class ScrollViewController: UIViewController, MyScrollViewDelegate {

var curQuestion: IPQuestion?
var type: QuestionViewType?
var lastClickedLabelTag: Int = 0 //

init(type: QuestionViewType, question: IPQuestion) {
    super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    self.curQuestion = question
    self.type = type
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func loadView() {
    view = MyScrollView(delegate: self, q: curQuestion!)
    view.userInteractionEnabled = true
}
}

// implementations for MyScrollViewDelegate
extension ScrollViewController {

func labelTitleArray() -> [String]? {
    print("labelTitleArray called in implemented delegate")

    return ["Comments", "Answers"]
}

func labelClicked(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    print("labelClicked called in implemented delegate")
    let controller = parentViewController as? ParentViewController
    controller?.labelClicked(recognizer)
    lastClickedLabelTag = recognizer.view!.tag
    }
}

// MARK: - handle parent's ViewController event
extension QuestionDetailViewController {
    func updateActiveLabelsColor(index: Int) {
        print("updating active labels color: \(index)")
        if let view = view as? MyScrollView {
            for label in (view.titleScroll.subviews[0].subviews as? [UILabel])! {
                if label.tag == index {
                    label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1,1.1)
                    label.textColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
                }
                else {
                    label.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1,1)
                    label.textColor = UIColor.blackColor()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This above `ScrollViewController` is added, as a child view controller to the parent view controller, and positioned to the top part of the parent's view:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
        addChildViewController(scrollViewController) // added as a child view controller here
        view.addSubview(scrollViewController.view) // here .view is MyScrollView
        scrollViewController.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
        scrollViewController.view.anchorToEdge(.Top, padding: 0, width: view.frame.size.width, height: 100)
    }
```

The app can load everything up in the view, but the tap gesture/events are not passed down to the labels in the custom `MyScrollView`. For this, I did some google search and have read [Event Delivery: Responder Chain](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/event_delivery_responder_chain/event_delivery_responder_chain.html) on Apple Developer website and did a hit test as well. The `hitTest` function below can be triggered in the `MyScrollView`:

```
override func hitTest(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        print("hit test started, point: \(point), event: \(event)")
        return self
    }
```

My observations with the `hitTest` is that the `touchesBegan()` and `touchesEnded()` methods are triggered in the view *only* when the `hitTest` function is there. Without `hitTest`, both functions do not get called with taps.

but no luck getting the `UILabel` to respond to Tap Gestures. So I am reaching out to experts on SO here. Thanks for helping!

Comment: Within the relevant touch methods on the parent, try forwarding them to the next responder. For example, within `touchesBegan` within the parent, try calling `self.nextResponder.touchesEnded`.

Comment: Have you set the property userInteractionEnabled = true for your labels? The default value is false for UILabel, so you should change it if you want to receive gestures.

Comment: @VladimirK, yes, I did set the `userIteractionEnabled` to true on all the labels. Thanks

Comment: The `self.nextResponder()?.touchesEnded()` seems to send the event up, not downward. The problem persists. Thanks

Comment: Ok, have you implemented delegate method for gesture recognizer that you added to label: gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:?

Comment: @VladimirK, yes, that has been implemented in the custom UIView, but does not work :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think I found out the reason why the `UILabel` did not respond to tapping after much struggle: the `.addGestureRecognizer()` method to the label was run in the `init()` method of my custom `UIView` component, which is *wrong*, because the *view/label* may not have been rendered yet. Instead, I moved that code to the lifecycle method `layoutSubviews()`, and everything started to work well:

```
var lastLabel: UILabel? = nil

        for i in 0..<scrollTitleArr.count {
            let label = UILabel()
            label.text = scrollTitleArr[i] ?? "nothing"
            print("label: \(label.text)")
            label.font = UIFont(name: "System", size: 15)
            label.textColor = (i == 0) ? MaterialColor.grey.lighten2 : MaterialColor.grey.darken2
            label.transform = (i == 0) ? CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1.1, 1.1) : CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.9, 0.9)
            label.sizeToFit()
            label.tag = i // for tracking the label by tag number
            label.userInteractionEnabled = true
            label.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.labelClicked(_:))))

            titleContainer.addSubview(label)

            if lastLabel == nil {
                label.anchorInCorner(.TopLeft, xPad: 0, yPad: 0, width: 85, height: 40)
      //         label.anchorToEdge(.Left, padding: 2, width: 85, height: 40)
            } else {
                label.align(.ToTheRightMatchingTop, relativeTo: lastLabel!, padding: labelHorizontalGap, width: 85, height: 40)
            }

            lastLabel = label

        }
```

In addition, I don't need to implement any of the UIGestureRecognizer delegate methods and I don't need to make the container view or the scroll view `userInteractionEnabled`. More importantly, when embedding the custom UIView to a superview, I configured its size and set `clipsToBounds = true`.

I guess I should have read more `UIView` documentation on the Apple Developer website. Hope this will help someone like me in the future! Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the property `userInteractionEnabled = YES`.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, my simulator was frozen or something when the tap gesture recognizer wasn't working. So, when I restarted the app, then it all worked again. I don't know if this applies here, but that was the fix for me.